# CD4543B Direct LED Driving Capability

Tags: current-limiting, 7segmentdisplay, decoder

I bought some 7 segment decoders specifically the CD4543B and the datasheet https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4543b.pdf mentions "Direct LED Driving Capability"

Does that mean I do not have to use current limiting resistors for each segment? (excluding the dp segment, of course)

I tried adding a 220ohm resistor for one of the segments but I couldn't see a noticeable brightness difference, and none of the segments has burnt out, yet.

I'm using common anode 7 segment displays if it makes a difference

Comment: What DC supply voltage do you use? The LEDS might survive having no series resistors, but the chip might overheat (especially with large VDD).

Comment: I'm using 5v, I didnt notice the chip warming up though

Answer (score 0):

If you look at page 3, there is no resistor to be seen.

So I guess you are lucky no LED has burnt out yet.

However, you can try with a digital (or analog) multimeter, to measure the current (Amperes). A typical 3 mm LED should not get more than 20 mA (and 40 mA is absolute maximum). General rule is always to stay under 20 mA (while using continuous current).

Comment: Thanks, I'll measure the current and have a look